# How to add a search domain to an existing search filter in Odoo?

Tags: view, odoo, extending, odoo-16

I added a new title field to a Sales Order.
Now I want to also be able to search by that field in the sales order list view.

If I run the following code, it works, but it seems like an overkill:

```
<record id="view_sales_order_filter_inherit_sale" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.filter.toledo.sale</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_sales_order_filter" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
           <!-- <field name="name" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="filter_domain">
                    "['|', '|',('name', 'ilike', self),('client_order_ref', 'ilike', self),'|',('partner_id', 'child_of', self),('title','ilike', self)]"
                </attribute>
            </field>
            -->
            <field name="name" position="replace">
                <field name="name" string="Order"
                    filter_domain="['|', '|',('name', 'ilike', self),('client_order_ref', 'ilike', self),'|',('partner_id', 'child_of', self),('title','ilike', self)]"/>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

I am looking for something more lean...like just replacing the domain for the "Order" filter...The following does not work:

```
<record id="view_sales_order_filter_inherit_sale" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.filter.toledo.sale</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_sales_order_filter" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
           <field name="name" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="filter_domain">
                    "['|', '|',('name', 'ilike', self),('client_order_ref', 'ilike', self),'|',('partner_id', 'child_of', self),('title','ilike', self)]"
                </attribute>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

giving an error:

> Caused by: InvalidDomainError: Invalid domain AST

Is it some issue with the domain itself or something else?
Can I use the position "attributes" to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Odoo [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/fr/developer/reference/backend/views.html#inheritance-specs):

> if the `attribute` element has a body, a new attributed named after its `name` is created on the matched node with the `attribute` element’s text as value

Odoo will add the quotes to the domain and make the domain incorrect, you need to remove the double quotes surrounding the domain list

If you get the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid field %s in leaf %s
```

Add the field to the search view.

Comment: Thanks @Kenly, thanks for translating the docs for this specific case. Removing the double quotes worked.